# Fill Datagridview with MySQL data

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

i tried several times to make it work but it just doesn't fill up the datagridview with mysql data ,here's my code :

```
string connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=shootsource;UID=root;PASSWORD=;";
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM characters";
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        sCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        sAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
        sBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
        sDs = new DataSet();
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "characters");
        sTable = sDs.Tables["characters"];
        connection.Close();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["characters"];
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

It shows only the columns from the mysql table 'characters' : id,name,time etc...how can i populate it from the db?

Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

Comment: It only shows the column **headers**? Is that what you mean? Are you sure there is even data in the table?

Comment: yeah there is..and yeah ..here's a picture : http://www.picz.ro/index.php?id=1dc2d2d989590d263a979c7a097124a0

Comment: I can't see anything wrong there

Comment: do you have any working code to test?

Comment: Nevermind got it but now it gives error , something about cannot convert date/time to string...??

Answer (score 14):

```
       private void MySQL_ToDatagridview()
    {
        //VarribleKeeper.MySQLConnectionString = your connection string
       //info being your table name
        MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new  

        MySqlConnection(VarribleKeeper.MySQLConnectionString);
        mysqlCon.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        string sqlSelectAll = "SELECT * from info";
        MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlSelectAll, mysqlCon);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MyDA.Fill(table);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = table;


        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set your DataSource you need to do a DataBind

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```