# Using C# & MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

I have been able to interface MySQL with my C# WinForms application with the help of wonderful guides all over the Internet, but I am confused as to which "method" is the standard way of doing so, if ever it does exist. To elaborate, I'll first describe the application that I am developing.

**C# Application Overview**

My application accepts input from the user, uses `DataGridView` as the main control for CRUD, and generates Excel reports. Basically, it does the below:

- Accept input and insert said data into the database
- Retrieve records and display them via `DataGridView`
- Update records using the `CellValueChanged` event
- Delete records
- Generate reports using Crystal Reports

**Using Objects**

What I currently do is to store and retrieve data as objects and use those for all of the above operations. For example:

```
public class Cat
{
    private int id;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string breed;
    public string Breed
    {
        get { return breed; }
        set { breed = value; }
    }

    public Cat(int id, string breed)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

For me to retrieve data, I do:

```
    public void FillCats()
    {
        cats = new List<Cat>();

        conn.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * from cat;";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Cat cat = new Cat(
                Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]),
                reader[1].ToString(),
            );
            cats.Add(cat);
        }

        reader.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Likewise, my create, update, and delete operations are simply variants of the below create function:

```
    public void Insert(DatabaseDriver db)
    {
        string insert = @"
        INSERT INTO cat(id, breed)
        VALUES(?id, ?breed);";

        db.open();
        db.setQuery(insert);
        db.setParameter("id", this.id);
        db.setParameter("breed", this.breed);
        db.executeNonQuery();
        db.close();
    }
```

Am I doing this right?

It does work, of course, but I was wondering whether there is a less time-consuming method, perhaps similar to how creating a DBML file would automatically connect your application to your SQL Server database, and even automagically associate every attribute with its corresponding primary key. Before anyone asks, unfortunately, it is not an option for me to use SQL Server.

Comment: You should consider using datasets and Entity framework to make your work a whole lot easier. You can then bind your DataGridViews to the datasets formed from your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer for a much less-involved way of doing it: [Fill Datagridview with MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904854/fill-datagridview-with-mysql-data)

As a side note, you can simply call `reader.GetInt32(0)` and `reader.GetString(1)` instead of `Convert.ToInt32(reader[0])` and `reader[1].ToString()`. That way you won't get a NullReferenceException when breed is null.