# Connection error when configuring MySQL data source in Configure Data Source wizard

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, mysql-workbench

I'm currently using VS2015 and a local instance of MySQL Server (managed through Workbench) to develop a school project.

The project is a Web form app (.NET/C#) which I have never really done before. I have done C# with a MySQL connection in the past but I think it was just a Windows form app, and I had no issues connecting the database to the form.

I'm currently trying to use a GridView element from the toolbox in Visual Studio to connect to my database. When I go in and edit the source settings, I can create a connection and it will see the tables in my database.

I can then click the "Test Connection" button and it will succeed in connecting. However, if I go forward and try to select items to view from the table, and then click "Test Query" I get the following error:

[image]

I have Googled the error and tried some of the solutions found on SO like installing the Clear MEF Cache extension, but it didn't solve anything.

Additionally, I've created some functions from scratch to connect and insert data. They also have problems in that trying to insert any more than one value into the table will fail. Like INSERT INTO user_info(user_id, user_name) VALUES ('5', "Bob") will insert the user_id but not the user_name.

Comment: Alternatively you can try to manually open a connection with code to ensure you can connect to it.

Answer (score 3):

Please see [here for a tutorial to connect to MySQL](http://solibnis.blogspot.com/2013/02/connecting-mysql-table-to-datagridview.html?m=1) and [here for filling your DataGridView from MySQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904854/fill-datagridview-with-mysql-data) Make sure you have the correct reference added to your project as well (References > MySQL.Data).