# Is that possible to return a whole join table data to datagridview instead of specifying the item one by one?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to get all data from the join table to data review, but what I learn is just to specify the attributes one by one in the SELECT statement as following code:

````
var query = (from inv in db.tblinventories
  join sup in db.tblsuppliers on inv.SupplierID equals sup.SupID into left
  from sup in left.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new { inv.Invnum,inv.Model, sup.name }).ToList();
                this.dgvPOS.DataSource = query;```
````

Is this the only way to fetch all data? Because in ORACLE SQL the way is quite simple by using "*" to represent all attributes like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblinventories 
LEFT JOIN tblsuppliers
ON tblinventories.SupplierID = tblsuppliers.SupID;
```

Comment: You can use `SELECT *` in populating a datagridview by binding it using a datatable.

Comment: Please look for other questions. This has been asked so many times.

Comment: Check this [Fill Datagridview with MySQL data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904854/fill-datagridview-with-mysql-data).